# Use sips to pad just the top of an image

Tags: sips

I'm trying to add padding to the top of an image using the command line.

I've found the `sips` command and I've tried

```
sips --padToHeightWidth 1300 1920 image.png
```

on an image which is 1920 x 1080.

However this adds 50px of padding to the top and bottom.

Is it possible to just add 100px of padding to the top?

Is there another tool I should/could be using to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe you can do that with `sips`. I would recommend `ImageMagick` which you can easily install using `Homebrew`. Then the command is:

```
convert  InputImage.jpg -background blue -splice 0x100 PaddedResult.jpg
```

[image]
[image]

If you want to add transparent padding, use:

```
convert  InputImage.jpg -background transparent -splice 0x100 out.png
```

If you want to composite two images together, you can do this:

```
convert -size 1024x768 xc:blue 1024x768.jpg                    # create big blue image
convert -size 100x100 xc:red 100x100.jpg                       # create little red image
composite -gravity northeast 100x100.jpg 1024x768.jpg out.jpg  # superimpose top right
```

Note that I am creating my images first, you can obviously just use your own.

[image]

Comment: Did this work for you? If so, please consider accepting it as the answer. If not, please say what went wrong so that I, or others, can assist you further.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would I be able to add transparent padding to a png using this method. And also would I be able to overlay other images and combine them into a single image? e.g I have a 1024x768 image and a 100x100 image and I want to put the 100x100 image in the top right corner of the 1024x768 image

Comment: Please have another look, I have updated my answer.